# iTunes help required

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipod, paypal

I'm setting up a friends iTunes account and he has 0.86$ left from a gift card and is otherwise linked to his paypal account.  The problem is, when I go to install an app on his iPod, it says that his account is declined and wont let him purchase anything right now either from the device or iTunes. The paypal account is currently in use with another iTunes account too, any ideas would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: not a real question; try google

Comment: You should contact Apple support regarding this. :)

Comment: C'mon guys...there's clearly a lot at stake here!

Comment: Yeah, this problem would be better handled by people at Apple or PayPal.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to actually resolve this is likely to be through contacting Apple Support.